# Perl bash command within a while loop produces nonsense

Tags: perl, while-loop

**Hello stackpeople!**

I have 2 things to solve and display the results online in a cgi-file.

**A)** get all foldernames at a given path

**B)** determine the age of the index.html inside each folder

the result should look like this:

[Number] [Foldername] [fileage]

This cgi-page runs on a solaris server with installed perl 5.8.4

My solution is a combination of bash and perl. To solve problem **A)** (the folder names) I have written a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
find /test/ -type d | sed -e 's/^.*\///'
```

This gives me a nice list of all foldernames in /test/

Now the perl code to show this output in a browser:

```
  #Establish a pipeline between the bash and my script.
  my $bash_command = '/test./foldernames.bash';
  open(my $pipe, '-|', $bash_command) or die "Can't open pipe: $!";
  # initialize variables
   my $foldername = "";
   my $i    = 0;

  # Process the output from bash command line by line.
  while (my $line = <$pipe>)
  {
   $foldername = $line;
   $i = $i+1;

   print"  <tr><td>$i</td><td>$foldername</td></tr>";
 }#end while
```

This works! I'll get a nice table with [Number] and [Foldername] ! Now comes the tricky part! In addition, I want the date of an index.html located in each folder. Therefore I have another bash script:

```
ls -ltr /test/folder1/*.html | tail -1 | awk '{printf"%3s %1s %s\n",$6, $7, $8}`
```

This gives me the perfect output: **Feb 22 10:56** Now I need this information in my table. I have added this line in my perl script within the while loop:

```
$timestamp = `ls -ltr /test/folder1/*.html | tail -1 | awk '{printf"%3s %1s %s\\n",\$6, \$7, \$8}`;
```

This works perfect when I add the foldername as a string. As soon as I exchange **folder1** with **$foldername** I'll get nonsense "ls" information.

Why is that so?

Edit: Now I have used:

```
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;
my $timestamp = ctime(stat("/test/folder1")->mtime);
```

This is way more secure compared to parsing the ls output. But still I have issues with the $foldername. I have used the **length** function to determine the length of *$Foldername*.

$foldername has a length of 7, but the string output has only 6 chars: tomato

So I've tried Chop/chomp the $foldername with always the same result: 7 chars!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, **don't parse `ls` output programmatically**. It's nearly guaranteed to break at some point, and to do so in some spectacular fashion. Parsing the output of `find` is only marginally safer (directory names on most Unixes can contain newline characters, for example; I don't see your code dealing well with that possibility).

Perl has [a `stat` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) which will give you the date and time of any file or directory (atime, mtime, or ctime, as available), as well as a bunch of other information. You can then use something like [`strftime`](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15533) to format these timestamps for nicer output.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you get different output because `$foldername` doesn't contain `"folder1"`.

In fact, looking at your earlier code, your lack of [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)ing would indicate that `$foldername` is far more likely to contain `"folder1\n"`.

Note that your approach will fail if `$foldername` contains a space, which is a pretty dumb limitation these days. Check out [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) or [File::stat](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3astat).

Comment: use File::stat; 
use Time::localtime; 

my $timestamp = ctime(stat("/test/folder1")->mtime); 

This is way more secure compared to parsing the ls output. But still I have issues with the $foldername. 

I have used the length function to determine the length of 
$Foldername. $foldername has a length of 7, but the string output has only 6 chars: tomato So I've tried Chop/chomp the $foldername with always the same result: 7 chars!